# somebody help,how can i remove the illegal record in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, assertions

I got a mongodb replset sync asserts
mongodb -version=2.4.8,
debian 64bit,
profile off

> Assertion: 10334:BSONObj size: 826530915 (0x3143DC63) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: ÜC1cÜC1cÜC1<9f>6Ifý^Btype: ?type=99

Then I checked collection for error details,using codes below:

```
cursor = db.collection.find();
err_count = 0;
 while(cursor.hasNext()){
    try{
        el = cursor.next();
        size = Object.bsonsize(el);
        print(el._id+":"+size);
    }
    catch(err){
            print(err_count ++);
            print(err);
    }
 }
```

about 4,000 errs found out of about 5,000,000 records,
those records loaded by mongoimport tool from a jsonfile which exports from an oldversion mongodb(should i try dump?)

everything was fine when i import those records,and query work well
the problem occured when sync to a new node in replset(in another net segment ,like 192.168.18.11:27017 sycn with 192.168.90.11:27017) 
currently,the replset master works well only with another node in the same net segment,(192.168.18.12).

**how can i fix it ,how to remove those error records?** through a bunch of useless infos in log file.
ive tried repair,do not work.

appreciate for your anwsers!

Comment: You have 4000 error records out of how many records? How was the data loaded in? What recently happened so these errors appeared? All of that information makes a useful edit to your question so people can understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to repair the database by

- [starting mongod with the --repair option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--repair)
- [using the db.repairDatabase()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.repairDatabase/#db.repairDatabase)
- [using mongodump with the --repair option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--repair)

Did you try one of those? What exact command(s) did you use, and what was the exact result?